# how can I use 'compare' sentence in findOneBy?

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$repository = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:items');
$items = $repository->findOneBy(
    array('isCancel' => false,
          'user' => $username,
          array('toDate' => 'ASC'));
```

I want to add comparing function as

```
  where registeredtime > now()
```

I can use compare sentence  with findOneBy?

or I have to write whole sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that as follows

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$repository = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:items');
$items = $repository->findOneBy(
    array('isCancel' => false,
    'user' => $username,
    array('toDate' => 'ASC'));
$criteria = Criteria::create()->where(Criteria::expr()->gt("registeredtime", now()));
$filteredItems = $items->matching($criteria);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try it:

```
...

$startDate = new DateTime();

$qb   = $repository->createQueryBuilder('e');
$event = $qb
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('e.start_date', ':start_date'))
    ->setParameter('start_date', $startDate)
    ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Comment: THank you for your comment!I use another answer but, it is good reference,thanks.